# Tomcat Java GC Issue Linux

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, tomcat7

I am running a Tomcat Web Server(7.0) on Ubuntu. I have the same War file using Java 1.6 in my local Windows machine and I face no issues whatsoever. However, on the linux machine my tomcat fails after some time or stops working and I get Java GC exceptions. It starts with these errors :

`Jul 10, 2011 4:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/manager]
Jul 10, 2011 4:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
SEVERE: IOException while saving persisted sessions: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/infocomm/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/manager/SESSIONS.ser (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/infocomm/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/manager/SESSIONS.ser (No such file or directory)`

Then these errors:

```
  Jul 10, 2011 4:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: JDBC driver de-registration failed for web application [/manager]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferencesJdbc(WebappClassLoader.java:2012)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearReferences(WebappClassLoader.java:1948)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.stop(WebappClassLoader.java:1860)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.stopInternal(WebappLoader.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5032)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:216)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1199)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1373)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Jul 10, 2011 4:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase destroy
INFO: The destroy() method was called on component [StandardContext[/manager]] after destroy() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
Jul 10, 2011 4:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
INFO: Undeploying context []
Jul 10, 2011 4:29:05 PM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
```

Then Finally TOmcat stops responding with these errors:

```
Jul 10, 2011 5:07:44 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase destroy
INFO: The destroy() method was called on component [StandardContext[/host-manager]] after destroy() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
Jul 10, 2011 6:31:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor rcbp.xml from /home/infocomm/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Would Appreciate any help.
This only happens after I exit the remote shell with which I started the Tomcat Application.

Answer (score 2):

does tomcat (when running with a specific user account) has access to this file, it should have enough privilege create, update & delete the file.

> /home/infocomm/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/manager/SESSIONS.ser

in windows its very rare for this scenario to surface unless you've started tomcat as an unprivileged user.

Comment: Yes, It has that privilege. I noticed this only happens when I exit the remote shell with which I tried to run Tomcat. I am trying to run it using the command  nohup bin/startup.sh >console.log 2>console.err </dev/null &